# Seaborn distplot for data with high SD

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to map float pd.Series with high SD:

```
>>>pd.Series(foo).describe()
count    3.351198e+07
mean    -2.337614e+02
std      4.788547e+04
min     -9.999999e+06
25%      0.000000e+00
50%      0.000000e+00
75%      0.000000e+00
max      7.499913e+07

>>>pd.Series(foo).std()
47885.47066964969
```

It is highly centered around 0 but has big tails and outliers on both sides.
So far I tried sns.distplot() with log scale but it only works on absolute values and I am interested in seeing difference on both sides.
How can I visualize in more detail both tails ?

my code so far:

```
bins = [0, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 100000, 100000000]
bins = [-i for i in bins[:1:-1] ] + bins
g = sns.distplot(foo.values,bins=bins,kde=False)
g.set_xscale('log')
```

[image]

Comment: First off, `sns.distplot` is an old function. You can use `sns.histplot()` instead. Also, the function returns an `ax`, not a `FacetGrid`. The negative values are in their appropriate bin, but setting `ax.set_xscale('log')` makes them invisible.  You could set `ax.set_xscale('symlog')` instead.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me tweak it further!